# Syntax for Entity Framework .Include()

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I am going crazy trying to get a handle on Linq include.

My main file is "Application" that has a GUID key of "Id" but I can't figure out the syntax to get it back without error.

```
public static Guid? ApplicationIdGet(string pApplicationName)
{
    return BrunoEntities.Set<AppApplication>().Include("Id").FirstOrDefault(p => p.LoweredName == pApplicationName.ToLower()).Id;
    //return BrunoEntities.AppApplications.Include(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault(p => p.LoweredName == pApplicationName.ToLower()).Id;
    //return brunoEntities.AppApplications.Include("Id").FirstOrDefault(p => p.LoweredName == pApplicationName.ToLower()).Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include is for where you want EF to load in *related* entities.  You don't need it to get normal properties of the entity you are requesting.  If you do want to have EF only fetch certain columns from the database, the Select function will let you control that